# Error:Type 'ASP._Page_views_index_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.UI.Page'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I had Asp.net web forms app, I want to convert it to responsive and to use Angularjs instead of web forms.

I started by adding two razor partial views:

1. views/login/login.cshtml
2. views/index.cshtml

Both views are pure html, except for rendering css/js

I also added to the routing:

```
routes.MapWebPageRoute("Login", "mobile/login", "~/views/login/login.cshtml");
routes.MapPageRoute("mobile", "mobile", "~/views/index.cshtml");
```

Now, when navigating to `mobile/login` will render with no problem, but navigating to `mobile` will give me the following error:

> Type 'ASP._Page_views_index_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.UI.Page'.

[image: error details]

I tried adding to `index.cshtml` the following:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
```

But got the same error!

Note: I don't have `<system.web.webPages.razor>` or `<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor">` in my web.config

Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you convert via a new project and migrating the markup and code.  The 2 tech are very different.

Comment: MY BAD! few hours trying to find it in code with no luck, after publishing here I just noticed it. 'mobile/login' use `MapWebPageRoute` extension instead of using the  `RouteCollection.MapPageRoute` which should be done to `mobile' also!

Comment: Thanks @TMcKeown, if it is were up to me I would do that!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following to the web.config file in the (Views) folder:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
```